# Hardcoding subtitles using mkvmerge recursivly

Tags: bash, video, video-editor, subtitle

I have 24 season 9, the folder has episodes and arabic subtitles. I want to automate the hardcoding  of the subtitles subtitles using a script. it looks like so

`24.903.hdtv-lol.mp4` and `24.903.hdtv-lol_ar.srt`

So far, I've been doing it manually using mkvmerge-gui, I select Charset: ara (Arabic), encoding WINDOWS-1256 destination: `newfolder/S9E3.mkv`

how to automate all that? so it will look for the subtitles corresponding to the episode, hardcode it using the options given above?

Comment: `mkvmerge` **does not hardcode** subtitles. That's the point of it.

Comment: @Oli but I  hardcoded the entire 24 season 9 using mkvmerge-gui, i don't know if it's hardocoding or not, all i know is that i did https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrVlmMpWvm8

Comment: Yeah that's just combining a video and a subtitle into a container. Hardcoding is rendering the subtitles over the video (and in doing so needing to recompress the video source).

Comment: Hardcoding means the subtitle is part of the image. As in you cannot deactivate it anymore. What you want is to have the subtitle added into the mkv file. You should change the title of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tick over the available .mp4 files and call mkvmerge on them.

```
for f in *.mp4; do
    mkvmerge "$f" "${f%.*}_ar.srt" -o "${f%.*}.mkv"
done
```

I'm not sure if the charset is needed but there is a `--sub-charset TID:character-set` argument. TID is the track number which I assume to be 0 or 1. Try it without first but if it doesn't work try adding `--sub-charset 0:WINDOWS-1256` to the command.

Comment: Not really related to the question, but I would suggest to add the `--clusters-in-meta-seek` parameter. I personally tested that it fixes seek and fast forward issues on some devices and video players. [Here](http://forum.serviio.org/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=3267) is a discussion about that.